# Difference between a differentiation rule and a differentiation formula

Tags: calculus

So I know that this is a rather trivial question, but I was just trying to think about it mathematically. So essentially a differentiation formula is using a secant line to approximate the slope as $h\rightarrow0$ while a differentiation rule provides the exact tangent line?

Comment: The "differentiation formula" is essentially the definition of a derivative. Differentiation rules are equations that arise as a consequence of the definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The slope of the tangent, aka the limit of the slope of local secants, is the *definition* of the derivative, not a formula. The limit of the secant lines will always be the exact tangent line, should one exist.

Differentiation rules allow you to calculate the derivative faster if you have an explicit expression for the function you are trying to differentiate.